# Interchanging the order of maximization and diffrentation

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let $f(x,y):\mathbb{R\times\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}}$ be a continuous and differentiable function. When can we claim that the following holds true:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\max_{y\in\mathbb{R}}f(x,y) = \max_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)
$$

assuming that both $\max_{y\in\mathbb{R}}f(x,y)$ and $\max_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ exists.

Comment: Have you tried a simple example, like a Gaussian $f(x,y)=\exp(-x^2-y^2+xy)$? I have a feeling the conjecture is rarely true.

Comment: The thing is that there is no reason to expect that the two maxima occur at the same location, so they are not likely to have anything to do with each other.

Comment: @RahulNarain I see. If we consider the *very simple* example of an affine function, then it works. The question is whether there is a condition on $f$ under which the equality holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose both maxima occur at the same location, that is, there is a function $g(x)$ such that
$$\begin{align}
f\big(x,g(x)\big) &= \max_{y\in\mathbb R} f(x,y), \\
f_x\big(x,g(x)\big) &= \max_{y\in\mathbb R} f_x(x,y),
\end{align}$$
where subscripts denote partial differentiation. Assuming differentiability in $y$, this implies that $\big(x,g(x)\big)$ is a zero of both $f_y(x,y)$ and $f_{xy}(x,y)$.
Then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\max_{y\in\mathbb R}f(x,y) &= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f\big(x,g(x)\big) \\
&= f_x\big(x,g(x)\big) + f_y\big(x,g(x)\big)g'(x) \\
&= \max_{y\in\mathbb R} f_x(x,y)
\end{align}$$
because $f_y\big(x,g(x)\big)=0$.

Thus, *if* both maxima coincide, then your claim holds. If not, I'd guess all bets are off.