# Can we bound the derivative *of* a max using derivatives *at* the max?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, optimization, non-convex-optimization

*Executive summary:* If we can bound the derivatives of some multivariate function with respect a continuous variable, do we automatically get bounds on the behavior of the maximum of that function with respect to other variables?

Here's the setup. Let $K$ be a compact topological space and let $f:\mathbb R\times K\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Suppose the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t, x)$ exists everywhere and, in fact, defines a continuous function $f':R\times K\to\mathbb R$. Define a function $Mf:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $Mf(t)=\max_{x\in K} f(t, x)$. Then $Mf$ is continuous, I'm pretty sure, but not necessarily differentiable. Nonetheless, the derivatives $f'$ **evaluated at the witnesses** of $Mf$ should bound the variation of $Mf$. Namely, if we focus our attention on $t$ around $0$ for simplicity:

- Let $MK(0)\subset K$ be the set of witnesses for $Mf(0)$. That is, $MK(0)$ is the set of $x\in K$ such that $f(0, x) = Mf(0) = \max_{y\in K}f(0, y)$. Or, if this notation is available, $MK(0)=\mathrm{Argmax}_{x\in K}f(0, x)$.
- Since $MK(0)$ is itself a compact set, we may define $Mf^+(0)=\max_{x\in MK(0)}f'(0, x)$ and $Mf^-(0)=\min_{x\in MK(0)}f'(0, x)$.

Then we should have the following conclusion:

- For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $t\in(-\delta,\delta)$, $t\neq 0$, the inequalities hold:

$$
Mf^-(0)-\epsilon < \frac{MF(t)-MF(0)}{t} < Mf^+(0)+\epsilon
$$

This feels like it ought to be an easy, well-known theorem, but I lack the terminology to find it.

If it helps, we can assume that $f'$ has a uniform bound, or that it has higher-order partial derivatives. Or we can restrict the domain of $t$ from $\mathbb R$ to $[-1,1]$. We can also assume that $K$ obeys separation axioms, but not that it's connected. For example, I want this result to hold if $K$ is a Cantor set.

Note that my question asks for something like a generalization of [Interchanging the order of maximization and diffrentation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502531/interchanging-the-order-of-maximization-and-diffrentation).

Comment: In the simplest case, e.g. $f\in C^2$, isn't it a taylor expansion corollary? Rewrite $f(t,x) = f(0, x) + f'(0,x)t + O(t^2)$, hence taking it for some $x^\ast \in MK(0)$ the equality is preserved. Moreover, $f(t, x^\ast) = f(0, x^\ast) + f'(0,x^\ast)t + O(t^2) \le f(0, x^\ast) + f'(0, y)t + O(t^2)$ with $y$ being a maximizer of $f'$ and similarly for the minimum.

Comment: In optimization theory, your function $F$ is called "value function" and you are asking about "sensitivity analysis". Have a look at section 4.3.1 in the book "Perturbation Analysis of Optimization Problems" by Bonnans & Shapiro.

Comment: @gerw Thank you, that's perfect! I don't have immediate access to the book, but I can already tell that their 1998 review article, "Optimization Problems with Perturbations: A Guided Tour", answers this question affirmatively with Theorem 4.1. It's available from the authors' websites [here](https://sites.gatech.edu/alexander-shapiro/files/2021/03/SIAM-R.pdf) and [here](https://inria.hal.science/inria-00073819/preview/RR-2872.pdf).